# com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.woden.resolver.URIResolver

Tags: java, jar, websphere, apache-axis, noclassdeffounderror

Deployed webservice based application on WebSphere 8.5.5.14 version.

What I've tried:

Set the parent last parameter in WebSphere
Rebuilding ear and webservices
Tomcat run war without any problems.
Added all the jar files path in Manifest.MF file.
verified that necessary jar file contains the URIResolver class.

Always getting below error.

```
ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet XXXXXX: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.woden.resolver.URIRes
olver
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:65)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:815)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.loadClassPathModules(RepositoryListener.java:222)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:71)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:64)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadFromClassPath(DeploymentEngine.java:177)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:135)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
```

ManiFest file Entries:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:lib/xmlschema-core-2.2.3.jar lib/xmlbeans-LICENSE.txt lib/wsdl4j-LICENSE.txt lib/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar lib/woden-core-LICENSE.txt lib/woden-core-1.0M10.jar lib/stax2-api.LICENSE.txt lib/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar lib/neethi-LICENSE.txt li
b/neethi-3.0.3.jar lib/mail-LICENSE.txt lib/mail-1.4.jar lib/log4j-LICENSE.txt lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar lib/httpcore-LICENSE.txt lib/httpcore-4.4.6.jar lib/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar lib/commons-logging-LICENSE.txt lib/commons-logg
ing-1.1.1.jar lib/commons-io-LICENSE.txt lib/commons-io-2.1.jar lib/commons-httpclient-LICENSE.txt lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar lib/commons-fileupload-LICENSE.txt lib/commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar lib/commons-codec-LICENSE.txt lib/commo
ns-codec-1.2.jar lib/commons-cli-LICENSE.txt lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar lib/axis2-xmlbeans-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-transport-xmpp-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-transport-udp-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-transport-tcp-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-transport-mail-1.7.9.jar l
ib/axis2-transport-local-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-transport-jms-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-transport-http-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-transport-base-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-spring-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-soapmonitor-servlet-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-saaj-1.7.9.jar lib/ax
is2-mtompolicy-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-metadata-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-kernel-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-json-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-jibx-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-jaxws-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-jaxbri-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-java2wsdl-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-fastinfoset-1
.7.9.jar lib/axis2-corba-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-codegen-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-clustering-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-ant-plugin-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-adb-codegen-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-adb-1.7.9.jar lib/axis2-LICENSE.txt lib/axiom-jaxb-1.2.21.jar lib/axio
m-impl-1.2.21.jar lib/axiom-dom-1.2.21.jar lib/axiom-api-1.2.21.jar lib/axiom-LICENSE.txt lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar lib/antlr-2-LICENSE.txt lib/activation-LICENSE.txt lib/activation-1.1.jar lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar lib/wsdl4j.jar lib/saaj.jar li
b/jaxrpc.jar lib/commons-logging.jar lib/commons-discovery-0.2.jar lib/axis.jar lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar lib/commons-codec-1.12.jar lib/wssec.jar lib/sas.jar lib/jlog.jar lib/javax.servlet_2.5.0.v200910301333.jar lib/javax.servlet.jsp_2
.0.0.v200806031607.jar lib/itim_server_api.jar lib/itim_common.jar lib/itim_api.jar lib/com.ibm.cv.kmip.ext.jar lib/api_ejb.jar lib/twilio-7.35.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar lib/axis2-jaxws-mar-1.7.9.jar

DisableIBMJAXWSEngine: true
~
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the URI resolver is in the woden api package, not the core. Adding this dependency should solve your issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.woden</groupId>
    <artifactId>woden-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0M9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Am new to build tools. am not using maven or spring framework. Am not sure where to add this dependency in a MVC project. I have tried to add this in EAR file lib and complied and ran it on WebSphere. But no luck. Still this is failing.

Comment: Add the library to the classpath, and add an entry in the Manifest also. That should solve your problem.